# React Native e hibrido?

Tags: android, ios, ionic, mobile, react

Eu queria saber se react native e realmente hibrido, como ionic, que você programa um código apenas e faz o export para as duas plataformas(IOS/ANDROID), ou e parecido com xamarin, que você faz os 2 códigos diferente.

No desenvolvimento do projeto eu programo como?apenas para uma plataforma por vez, ou cada uma individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o React Native, você programa em Javascript e o seu código será "traduzido" para componentes nativos de cada plataforma. Quando você declarar um `Text`, por exemplo, ele será traduzido para um `UIView` no iOS e para um `TextView` no Android.

Com o Ionic, você também programa em Javascript, mas seu código vai rodar dentro de um `WebView`, podendo gerar uma diferença de desempenho.

Acredito que qualquer ferramenta para desenvolvimento híbrido vai oferecer maneiras de fazer personalizações para as diferentes plataformas, já que cada plataforma tem suas peculiaridades.

Desta forma, o fluxo normal de desenvolvimento, tanto no Ionic como React Native, é fazer um código só para ambas plataformas. Caso necessário, existe a possibilidade de fazer personalizações para cada paltaforma.